# Replace single quotes in double quotes in brackets

Tags: json, regex, sed

I must modify a file json. I must replace the single quotes in double quotes but I can't use the following command `sed -i -r "s/'/\"/g" file` because in the file there are more single quotes that I don't change.

The following code is an example of string:

```
"categories": [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Girls'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'More Accessories', 'Kids & Baby']]
```

The desided result should be:

```
"categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Girls"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Novelty, Costumes & More", "Costumes & Accessories", "More Accessories", "Kids & Baby"]]
```

sample file:

```
{"categories": [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], "title": "Understanding Seizures and Epilepsy DVD"},
{"title": "Who on Earth is Tom Baker?", "salesRank": {"Books": 3843450}, "categories": [['Books']]},
{"categories": [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Girls'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'More Accessories', 'Kids & Baby']], "description": "description, "title": "Mog's Kittens", "salesRank": {"Books": 1760368}}},
{"description": "Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles", "brand": "Dr. Seuss", "categories": [['Toys & Games', 'Puzzles', 'Jigsaw Puzzles']]},
```

I used a regular expression but the problem is that I don't know how many element are in brackets. So I would a way for replace all single quotes in the brackets, this is a perfect way, but I can not find the solution.

Comment: you mean you can only change quotes in given lines? Can you post a (small) full json file?

Comment: {"categories": [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], "title": "Understanding Seizures and Epilepsy DVD"},
{"title": "Who on Earth is Tom Baker?", "salesRank": {"Books": 3843450}, "categories": [['Books']]},
{"categories": [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Girls'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'More Accessories', 'Kids & Baby']], "description": "description", "title": "Mog's Kittens", "salesRank": {"Books": 1760368}}},
{"description": "Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles", "brand": "Dr. Seuss", "categories": [['Toys & Games', 'Puzzles', 'Jigsaw Puzzles']]},

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to read... but if you see the field "categories", I would change the single quotes in double quotes... but there are different number of string in that field.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post with your comment. line formatting was lost so if you want you can [edit] again. The only problem I see is that changing to single quotes everywhere will trash `"Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles"` because there's a quote in the string. Is that your problem? because it's a big one.

Comment: thanks for the modify, I edited the post. Anyway, the problem is not the field "description" but the "categories"... I would change only the single quotes in that field... but, as I said, I can't use this `sed -i -r "s/'/\"/g" file`, because, in this way, I change also the other single quotes (like "Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles"), and I don't want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that, using python.

Note that the json stream you provided is not recognized by python json because of single quotes (and also some copy/paste problems, missing quotes, I fixed that).

My solution is using fully the python libraries, I doubt you can do the same with `sed`, that's why I provide it despite the fact you didn't mention that technology.

- I read the data using `ast.literal_eval` since it's a list of dictionaries with the exact python syntax. Single quotes are not a problem for `ast`
- I write the data using `json.dump`. It writes the data using double quotes.
- Note that I write it in a "fake" file (i.e. a string with I/O write method to "fool" the json serializer).

Here's a standalone snippet that works:

```
import io

foo = """[{"categories": [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']], "title": "Understanding Seizures and Epilepsy DVD"},
{"title": "Who on Earth is Tom Baker?", "salesRank": {"Books": 3843450}, "categories": [['Books']]},
{"categories": [['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Girls'], ['Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry', 'Novelty, Costumes & More', 'Costumes & Accessories', 'More Accessories', 'Kids & Baby']], "description": "description", "title": "Mog's Kittens", "salesRank": {"Books": 1760368}},
{"description": "Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles",
"brand": "Dr. Seuss", "categories": [['Toys & Games', 'Puzzles', 'Jigsaw Puzzles']]}
]"""

fp = io.StringIO()

json_data=ast.literal_eval(foo)
json.dump(json_data,fp)
print(fp.getvalue())
```

result:

```
[{"categories": [["Movies & TV", "Movies"]], "title": "Understanding Seizures and Epilepsy DVD"}, {"salesRank": {"Books": 3843450}, "categories": [["Books"]], "title": "Who on Earth is Tom Baker?"}, {"description": "description", "salesRank": {"Books": 1760368}, "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Girls"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Novelty, Costumes & More", "Costumes & Accessories", "More Accessories", "Kids & Baby"]], "title": "Mog's Kittens"}, {"brand": "Dr. Seuss", "description": "Three Dr. Suess' Puzzles", "categories": [["Toys & Games", "Puzzles", "Jigsaw Puzzles"]]}]
```

Here's a full script taking 2 parameters (input file & output file) and performing the conversion. You can use this script within your already existing bash scripts if you're not comfortable with python (save that in `fix_quotes.py` for instance):

```
import ast,json,sys

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

with open(input_file,"r") as fr:
    json_data=ast.literal_eval(fr.read())
with open(output_file,"w") as fw:
    json.dump(json_data,fw)
```

Comment: Interesting! I used [sed] because the file that I must changed is very large... But I can not find the solution, so I accept other solutions... this works if I use a json file, instead of a string? I mean, there is a function to load a the file for use this solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the solution I was looking for... one last thing, if I try to do it with a very large file, I can end up executing? lol

Comment: the standalone example is given in the end. If the file exceeds the machine memory (well below that limit actually), this will fail because data is loaded at once. Note that I added square brackets at start and in the end to be able to process that as a list of dictionaries. One could imagine load 1 line at a time (dropping the square brackets) and writing one 1 line at a time (one dict at a time).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try your solution with my file very soon... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# read each line from stdin
while (my $l=<>) {    
   chomp($l); # remove newline char

   # split: get contents of innermost square brackets
   my @a=split(/(\[[^][]*\])/,$l);

   foreach my $i (@a) {
      # replace quotes iff innermost square brackets
      if ($i=~/^\[/) { $i=~s/'/"/g; }
   }

   # join and print
   print join('',@a)."\n";
}
```